# Parametric equations for "precessing orbits"

Tags: differential-geometry

I have somewhat of a strange question. I know this might be better suited for Physics Stack Exchange, but considering I'm only using the phrase "precessing orbit" as an analogy to describe the kind of curve I want to parametrize, I figured I might as well ask here first. Please let me know if this post should be redirected to the PSE forums.

So, on the one hand I have parametric curve $f(t)=(\cos(t),0,\sin(t))$  for all $t\in\mathbb{R}$ (the orientation of the curve and the plane where it lies don't really matter to me; I only chose them for convenience). On the other hand, I know that I can use the matrix

\begin{align}
R=\left[\begin{array}{ccc} \cos(\theta) & \sin(\theta) & 0 \\ \sin(\theta) & \cos(\theta) & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \end{array} \right]
\end{align}
to rotate the curve around the $z$ axis by $\theta$ radians. Again, I could have used an arbitrary orthogonal matrix $R$ such that $det(R)=1$, but I chose this particular set of rotations for convenience.

Now, what I would like to do is to describe a curve that in a way does both things at the same time, like a drifting or precessing orbit, so to speak. I also would like to include a parameter that controls how much this "orbit drifts per rotation", if that makes any sense.

If it helps make things a bit clearer, I got this idea from artificial satellites that don't orbit on a fixed plane, but rather slowly drift, sweeping the entire surface of the Earth after enough time passes. I'm not attempting to model the orbital mechanics at all, though. I'm just interested in giving a parametrization of a curve that describes this kind of orbit.

If possible, since I'm doing this for fun, I would like you to avoid giving me the answer right away. Instead, I would like some hints that help me figure this out by myself, unless the math is way too complicated. That said, I reckon this problem shouldn't involve any tools that I'm not familiar with.

EDIT: I'm looking for something along the lines of this:

\begin{align}
(\cos(t)\cos(\alpha t), \sin(t)\cos(\alpha t),\sin(\alpha t))
\end{align}

I'm not sure yet if this is exactly what I was looking for but for values of $\alpha$ larger than 4 it starts to resemble the kind of behaviour I had in my head.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is essentially adding a phase angle that varies (slowly?) with time, i.e., a parametrization like $(\cos(\theta t + t), \sin(\theta t + t))$ should do.

Comment: Unfortunately that is not what I'm looking for. The curve given by that parametrization will still be a circumference, even if I add another coordinate to make it a curve in 3D space. I don't know how I should explain it. This would be easier if I had a picture of the kind of curve I'm trying to describe.

Comment: I just added a parametrization of a family of curves that more closely resemble what I had in mind for sufficiently large values of \alpha.